# How to access alfresco global property from a share client-side javascript?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have the following property in my alfresco-global-properties file.

`customAction.enabled=true`

I want to access this value from custom-actions.js file in share. What is the best and easiest way to do achieve this? Can I use rootScope variable in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access alfresco-global-properties from the javascript api for security reasons. Either you implement your custom getter in Java and expose that to javascript or you store your required config in a specific content node which will be accessable from javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I created a webscript to get the value of the property from the global properties.